# Creating QGIS processing algorithm that works asynchronously?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am writing a QGIS processing algorithm that reads rows including addresses from a CSV file. The addresses are geocoded one by one via external REST API and then a vector layer containing the point features corresponding each row is created. The layer is saved to a file and possibly also opened in the QGIS.

I am using QGIS 3.0 but if someone knows how this should be handled in QGIS 2.x that would also be helpful. I am planning to use the `PyQt5.QtNetwork` module for the REST API calls.

Is it possible to do the REST API calls asynchronously and when they all have finished then finish the processing algorithm?

If not, what is the proper way to handle this kind of process?

Comment: In python 3 use [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), for python 2 use the backported [`futures`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) (needs to be installed via pip/conda).

Comment: @luke Thank you for the suggestion. I decided to not to make asynchronous REST API calls but instead to use `urllib` to make the API calls that works fine for my needs.

Comment: You can use urllib (or even better, the `requests` package) with concurrent.futures. I assume that the REST calls would be the bottleneck in your code so makes sense to run them asynchronously.

Comment: See also https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-futures

Comment: Thank you @luke. I actually think it is not good idea to do a lot of REST calls to the same server at the same time as it will consume server resources and could even be considered DOS attack. But I agree with you that there are situations where asynchronous processing algorithms and also the futures and requests libraries with them would be useful.